# How to prevent Selenium from opening a pop-up to save the file?

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, browser, selenium-webdriver, popup

I'm scraping the site **[Quicker.com](http://mumbai.quikr.com/Individual/0-50000000/Houses-Apartments-for-Sale/w1072?imageAds=Y&l=You_are-Price&page=5)** but every time getting an error on random pages.
The error is:

```
UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: C:\Users\HEYPIL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Pkwnr4IA.php.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.

Try again later, or contact the server administrator.
<super: <class 'WebDriverException'>, <UnexpectedAlertPresentException object>>
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
import re
import hashlib
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import socket
import time
import datetime

ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date = st.encode('utf8')


IPAdd = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

counter = 5
initial = []

base = "http://mumbai.quikr.com/Individual/0-50000000/Houses-Apartments-for-Sale/w1072?imageAds=Y&l=You_are-Price"
string = "&page="



while(counter == 5 or counter < 40):
    base2 = base+string+str(counter)
  if  (counter < 39):
    initial.append(base2)

elif(counter == 40):
    initial.append(base)

else:
    base2 = base

counter += 1
for n in initial:

result = []

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(n)

main_page = '//a[@class="adttllnk unbold"]'
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(main_page):
    l = a.get_attribute('href')
    result.append(l)

print len(result)
driver.close()



for url in result:
    try:
    
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(url)
        items = []

        desc_path = '//div[@id="ad_description"]'
        img_path = '//div[@class="bigImg_wapp"]//img[@src]'
        prop = '//div[@itemprop="name"]//h1[@class="ad_title translate"]'
        amenities = '//div[@class="ad-atrbt-panel"]//span[@class="ad-atrbt-val"]//span[@class="attribVal newattribVal"]'
        phone = '//span[@class="NoVerified-Text"]'

        for x1 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(img_path):
            img = (x1.get_attribute('src')).encode('utf8')
            print '\n'+img

        for x2 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(desc_path):
            desc = (x2.text).encode('utf8')
            print '\n'+ desc

        for x3 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(prop):
            prop_title = (x3.text).encode('utf8')
            print '\n'+prop_title

        for x4 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(amenities):
            value = (x4.text).encode('utf8')
            items.append(value)
        print '\n'
        print items
        locality = items[0]
        locality1 = locality.encode('utf8')
        a = (locality1 if (isinstance(locality1,int) == False) else "")

        bhk = items[1]
        bhk1 = bhk.encode('utf8')
        if(bhk1 == "4+ BHK"):
            b = "4"
        else:
            bhk2 = [int(z) for z in bhk1.split() if z.isdigit()]
            b = ((str(bhk2).strip('[')).strip(']')).strip()

        furnish = items[2]
        if(isinstance(furnish,int) == False ):
            furnish1 = furnish.encode('utf8')
            if((furnish1 == "Semi-Furnished") or (furnish1 == "Unfurnished") or (furnish1 == "Fully Furnished") or (furnish1 == "Unfurnished,Unf...")):
                c = furnish1
            else:
                d = furnish1
        elif(isinstance(furnish,int) == True):
            furnish1 = furnish.encode('utf8')
            d = furnish1
        else:
            c = ""

        sqft = items[3]
        if(isinstance(sqft,int)==True):
            sqft1 = [int(xyz) for xyz in sqft.split() if xyz.isdigit()]
            sqft2 = ((str(sqft1).strip('[')).strip(']')).strip()
            d = sqft2.encode('utf8')
        elif(isinstance(sqft,int)==False):
            sqft1 = sqft.encode('utf8')
            if((sqft1 == "Semi-Furnished") or (sqft1 == "Unfurnished") or (sqft1 == "Fully Furnished") or (sqft1 == "Unfurnished,Unf...")):
                c = sqft1
            else:
                d = sqft1
                
            
        else:
            d = ""

        atz = '\t'

        print a,atz,b,atz,c,atz,d

        for x5 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(phone):
            biz = (((x5.text).lstrip('+91')).strip()).encode('utf8')
            if(len(biz)== 9):
               biz_phone = '9'+biz
               
            elif(len(biz) < 7 and len(biz) > 4):
                biz_phone = '080'+biz

            elif(len(biz) > 9 or len(biz) < 12):
                biz_phone = biz

            elif(len(biz) == 4 or len(biz) < 4):
                biz_phone = biz.strip(biz)

            else:
                print '\nInvalid Business_phone'

            print '\n'+biz_phone

        driver.close()




        hash_key = hashlib.md5("marketing@"+biz_phone+".com"+"Individual"+prop_title).hexdigest()
        unique_key = ('I_'+hash_key).encode('utf8')

        
        
    except (NameError, IndexError, WebDriverException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException) as e:
        print "Failed to open: "+url
        driver.close()

        fieldname = ['Date','URL']
        with open("C:\Users\Heypillow\Desktop\scrapWork\properties\\Failed_to_open_url.csv",'a') as h:
            write = csv.DictWriter(h,fieldnames=fieldname,lineterminator = '\n')
            write.writerow({'Date':date,
                            'URL':url})
```

I've blocked the pop-up in Firefox() but yet a pop-up is coming which addressing me to save a **.php** file and raises this exception.
I've already used that exception in the **"except"** part yet it's interrupting the code to work further and it's getting stopped just after this exception rises.

So, every time this exception rises, I have to restart the program. Thus I would like to download all the data by running the code through out the night,which is impossible with this circumstances…

How can I prevent this pop-up from opening?

(*If I would have been able to upload a screenshot of the pop-up,it would have been easier to understand it.*)

Comment: You can link to an image. Get an Imgur account (they're free) then upload your screenshot there then link to it here. [Like so](http://i.imgur.com/I9CHQBY.png)

Comment: Ok,means we can't directly upload image here right?
Thanks that's what I needed to know.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about stack overflow, not software development